# Understanding the performance of a web application made in Angular

Tags: angular, performance

when it comes to cleaning an angular web application that has been in production for a long time, what really matters in terms of performance (and not just build)?

Does the dependencies in package.json have a lot of impact for the user (regardless of whether they are being used or imported into app.module)? Does devDependencies have no impact at all? I believe that everything inside the appModule, regardless of whether it is being used in components, becomes a .js that will be downloaded by the user. And if I do a lazy loading of a directive/pipe that needs to be imported in several modules, will the user have to download the same directive/pipe several times?

Comment: What does "Cleaning an Angular Web Application" mean?  Unused dependencies in a package.json should not be included in your final build as part of the Angular CLI's optimization process.  But, if you have code that is using those dependencies, it could be ballooning the app's initial download size.

Comment: Sorry for my bad translation! I am referring to an application that has been in production for a long time and has a lot of library installed (due to it was made by several different developers), and some libs that do practically the same thing (for example using font-awesome, the alyle icon and the material icon) but that I really don't know if cleaning these things will actually have a big impact on performance (taking into account that it will be a lot of work to review each library).

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts (personal experience, but nothing more) :-)

First "Performance" is a buzzword without content. So you have to clarify, WHAT performance do you want to enhance?

- reduce the amount of traffic that goes over the network
- reduce the memory consumption
- reduce the CPU usage
- increase the reaction speed of the page
- ...

So first you have to know what exactly your problem is. And then you need to kind of "measure" it. Only then you are able to compare the result of your changes to the prior situation.

If you use Angular Ivy, with activated tree shaking, then the unsued dependencies will not effect your application, because they already get removed in the build. If you use an older Angular version (without Ivy) or if you have tree shaking disabled, then those dependencies are dead code that is packed in your final artefact. That means the user has to load more data then necessary to use your application.

Out of a maintenance perspective, i would clean up the package.json. Then the application becomes easier to understand (one solution for a problem and not three) and therefor easier to maintain.

If your application is rarely changed and your users are always the same, then i would expect that your application is in most cases already cached in the browser, therefor the cleaning would have nearly no effect, because there is already nearly no traffic.

Lazy Loading is nice, because it "moves" the loading time into the background, while the user hopefully can already do something useful with the app. On the other side it appends complexity, because now you have to make sure that the user is not able to reach a point in your application where he would need those modules if they are not already loaded.

Long story short:
Improving performance starts with understanding where currently problems are. And then in most cases, improving the performance mean to make the application more complex.

If a pure "Clean up" gives you a bit of performance, nice. But i would do the clean up just because it helps in so many ways, there the performance gain is just a nice addon.

I hope some of the points help you a bit
warm regards